# Selenium find by xpath very slow for first search on page

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am writing selenium automated tests on a dojo based web application.

On one of the pages I test on the first search by Xpath is slow (about 30 seconds; this is slow for my case - all other pages react in a matter of second). This is true no matter which is hte first element I interact with - be it a check against `isDisplayed` or `click` interaction.

All this makes me believe that on the first XPath query on a particular page some caching is happenning. Is there someone who can shed some light? How can I optimise this precomputing, is there a way I can switch off this caching?

My environment:

- Java 1.7
- Java selenium 2.52.0
- Mozilla Firefox 38.0.5

Thanks for the help!

Comment: After I create my driver the next statement is: driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 In my case it is not the cookie cache causing the problem. I am already deleted on cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your implicit wait set at?  Does the page show a loading spinner while it loads?

Page loading doesn't happen in an instant. That page may be running JavaScript to load elements. Assuming that your implicit wait is on the order of 30+ seconds, that first findElement may be waiting for the element to be loaded.

Check to see if that page uses jQuery (if you open the page source does it contain 'jquery'?)  If so, google *webdriver wait return jQuery.active*

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. My implicit wait is 10 seconds. The page seem to be fully loaded when I mstart measuring these 30 seconds I report. The application is Dojo based, as long as I can tell this means a lot of javascript is involved, but no JQuery per se.

Comment: Hey Atually after I switched on FireBug and monitored the network tab I found out there are two AJAX calls that take rather a long time (justifying my 30+ seconds delay). This is also telling us why no page loading indicator is visible, but the elements are not loaded. Iw ill go forth and accept your answer as you seem to have covered this case.